# StringかArrayかを判定したい

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptで変数に入っている値が文字列か文字列の配列かによって処理を分けたいです。
厳密に配列の中身が文字列であるかどうかまではチェックしなくて良いです。

```
var stringOrArray = someFunc();

if (argumentIsString(stringOrArray)) {
  // 文字列が渡された時の処理

} else if (argumentIsArray(stringOrArray)) {
  // 配列が渡された時の処理

}
```

上記`argumentIsString`, `argumentIsArray`にあたる処理はどのようになりますか？
どちらか片方がわかればもう片方は `else` でも良いですが、できれば今後の変更を見据えて文字列・配列それぞれの判定をしたいです。

ちなみにIE8以上の対応が必要です。

Answer (score 5):

こちらが参考になると思います。
[JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#types.typeof)
[日本語訳](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/ja/#types.typeof)

```
function is(type, obj) {
    var clas = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1);
    return obj !== undefined && obj !== null && clas === type;
}

is('String', 'test'); // true
is('String', new String('test')); // true
```

Comment: JavaScript Garden の記述が、とても良かったです。

Answer (score 3):

あんまり汎用性はありませんが、
お手軽にするならこうでしょうか？

```
var stringOrArray = someFunc();

if (typeof(stringOrArray) == "string" || stringOrArray instanceof String) {
  // 文字列が渡された時の処理
} else if (stringOrArray instanceof Array) {
  // 配列が渡された時の処理
}
```

[追記]

既に他の回答のコメントで言及されていますが、
ArrayやStringそのものを上書きされてしまった場合、この方法は破綻します。
方法は極めて単純で、判定前に

```
/* fooやbarの中身は適当 */
String = foo
Array = bar
```

と書かれた場合はアウトとなります。

Comment: 文字列のときだけtypeofとinstanceof併用なのって理由があるんでしょうか？

Comment: JavaScriptの文字列判定は"123"とnew String(123)で挙動が違ってしまう仕様がありまして、"123"はtypeofで判定する必要があり、new String(123)はinstanceofで判定する必要があります。
対して配列は[1, 2, 3]とnew Array(1, 2, 3)の両方をinstanceofで判定することができます。
他の方の回答は、そのあたりを汎用的にするような解決法を用いています。

Answer (score 1):

ちょっと変わった方向として [underscore.js のソース](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/044ba5c3502dfac26c1a863a62c518b91e2a255d/underscore.js#L1210-L1215) を見ると、`Object.prototype.toString.call(v)` して、返ってきた文字列を比較してますね。

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]'

Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object String]'
```

# なんでこうするんだろ… `instanceof` だけで十分に思うけれども

Comment: `String` や `Array` という関数をユーザーがグローバルに定義していた時には、`instanceof` が意図通りには動かないですね。やはり underscore.js などのライブラリ(もしくはそこで用いられている手法)を使うのが、堅実そうです。

Comment: そんなことを言ったら、toStringで返される文字列はES6環境であれば自由に設定できますよ。

Answer (score 0):

本家に同様の質問がありました
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058427/how-to-detect-if-a-variable-is-an-array

`Array.isArray`ってIE8で使えるのかな。。。？